# How to change partition scheme with arduino-cli

Tags: esp32, arduino-cli

I'm using arduino-cli to program an ESP32-S2.  If I compile my sketch using the default partition scheme

```
> arduino-cli compile -b esp32:esp32:esp32s2 sketch
```

a lot of space is allocated for SPIFFS and OTA, which I don't use.

```
Sketch uses 646558 bytes (49%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
Global variables use 39540 bytes (12%) of dynamic memory, leaving 288140 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
```

Thus. I'd like to use the `huge_app` scheme, as defined in the boards.txt:

```
esp32s2.menu.PartitionScheme.huge_app=Huge APP (3MB No OTA/1MB SPIFFS)
esp32s2.menu.PartitionScheme.huge_app.build.partitions=huge_app
esp32s2.menu.PartitionScheme.huge_app.upload.maximum_size=3145728
```

However, selecting it doesn't have any effect:

```
> arduino-cli compile -b esp32:esp32:esp32s2 sketch --build-property build.partitions=huge_app
Sketch uses 646558 bytes (49%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.
Global variables use 39540 bytes (12%) of dynamic memory, leaving 288140 bytes for local variables. Maximum is 327680 bytes.
```

Is my command line incorrect?  Why is arduino-cli not using the specified partition scheme?

Comment: according to platform.txt it is `build.custom_partitions` the value is the selected partitioning from boards.txt

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, I've checked platform.txt and found `custom_partitions` as well.  Unfortunately, it didn't help: `arduino-cli compile sketch --build-property build.custom_partitions=huge_app` results in `Sketch uses 646558 bytes (49%) of program storage space. Maximum is 1310720 bytes.`

Comment: Are you uploading the bin file by arduino-cli?

Answer (score 2):

So, it turns out I have to add another build property:

```
> arduino-cli compile --build-property build.partitions=huge_app --build-property upload.maximum_size=3145728 sketch
```

where the `upload.maximum.size` is from the `boards.txt` file.  Indeed, a maze of twisty little files, all alike.

Comment: Just like the original Adventure. :)